parse .docx file with elements in markup compatibility namespace in python3
I have a .docx file containing the following piece of code in its document.xml
<w:document 
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
    xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing"
    xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word">
<mc:AlternateContent>
            <mc:Choice Requires="wps">
                <w:drawing>
                    <!-- ... -->
                </w:drawing>
            </mc:Choice>
            <mc:Fallback>
                <w:pict>
                    <v:shape type="#_x0000_t202" filled="f" stroked="f"
                        style="margin-left:749pt;margin-top:0pt;width:205pt;height:112pt;mso-position-vertical:absolute;mso-position-vertical-relative:text;mso-position-horizontal:absolute;mso-position-horizontal-relative:text;mso-wrap-style:square;position:absolute;v-text-anchor:top;">
                        <w10:wrap type="topAndBottom" />
                        <v:textbox inset="0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt" style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:t">
                            <w:txbxContent>
                                <w:p>
                                    <!-- ... -->
                                </w:p>
                            </w:txbxContent>
                        </v:textbox>
                    </v:shape>
                </w:pict>
            </mc:Fallback>
        </mc:AlternateContent>
</w:document>

I need to access <w:p>, which is accessible with doc.paragraphs in general case with python-docx. But those inside <mc:AlternateContent> is completely ignored, i.e. it is not accessible by doc.paragraphs. So I wonder what may be a good practice to do the job.
I have one idea: using lxml to replace the <mc:AlternateContent> by the content inside <mc:Fallback> everywhere in document.xml and then send the result to python-docx, does that make sense?

this answer could give an starting point https://stackoverflow.com/a/78318170/2834978

What do you need to do with this XML?

@Parfait I need to access <w:p>, which is accessible with doc.paragraphs in general case, but here <w:p> is inside <mc:AlternateContent>, which makes python-docx fail to retrieve it.

@mzjn I just use doc = docx.Document("example.docx") and then for para in doc.paragraphs: print(para.text) where the text inside <w:p> inside <mc:AlternateContent> is not printed out.
As replied by the contributor, it is just not accessible with the proxy class paragraph, so I think I should go with my proposed idea.

@mzjn I did post it in my question... I thought you didn't notice.

What do you then need to do with <w:p> content? I don't know the other package but lxml can parse any well-formed XML, namespaces and all.

@Parfait oh, it's just because python-docx has a nice wrap up for parsing the wordprocessingML(the specific xml used by docx file), which is easier to extract formats and content. Yeah indeed it's kind of a niche package, so I just seek for luck.
